# OutOfMemory Exception - Hive multi join query in HDInsight LLAP cluster

Tags: azure, join, hive, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

I am trying a hive multi join query in Azure HDInsight LLAP Hive Cluster.

It is giving **OutOfMemory** exception after running for 20 mints approx.

Query:

> create table tt as SELECT given_qad_sedol as Sedol7, f.ws_cd, f.ws_id,
>   f.cntry_cd, f.cntry_name, f.entity_name, f.stmt_sub_typ,
>   f.stmt_sub_typ_desc, f.stmt_typ, f.stmt_typ_desc, f.item, f.item_name,
>   f.short_mnem, f.item_mnem, coalesce(f1.frq, f.frq) as frq,
>   coalesce(f1.frq_desc, f.frq_desc) as frq_desc, f.yr, f.seq,
>   f.fiscal_per_end_date, coalesce(f1.erng_rpt_date, f.erng_rpt_date) as
>   erng_rpt_date, f.per_update_flg, f.per_update_desc, f.per_srce,
>   f.reported_curr, coalesce(f1.reported_val, f.reported_val) as
>   reported_val, f.exch_rate, f.ws_curr, f.unit_typ FROM
>   imdl_irdp_dev.cur_std_fundamentals f JOIN
>   imdl_irdp_dev.cur_ws_comp_map cm ON f.ws_cd = cm.ws_cd  JOIN
>   imdl_irdp_dev.cur_scrty_sedol_chg_hstry s ON cm.qad_scrty_cd =
>   s.qad_scrty_cd AND cm.typ = s.typ  LEFT JOIN
>   **imdl_irdp_dev.cur_std_fundamentals** f1 ON f.ws_cd = f1.ws_cd AND f.item = f1.item AND f.yr = f1.yr AND f.seq = f1.seq AND f1.frq = 'B'
>   ORDER BY yr,seq,stmt_typ_desc,item;

Highlighted table has around 1.5 billion records. We can't change the query as it is business requirement. But we can optimize it provided result of query should not be changed.

I have tried below options as well, but still no luck.

```
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=8000;
set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx46080m;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8000;
set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx7000m;
set hive.tez.container.size=8000;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx7000m;   
set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=1000000000;
set set dfs.blocksize=1073741824;
```

Is there any way we can optimize this query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow 2 best practices. Introduce partition to read the necessary data and change the file format to ORC as you are selecting only a few columns. This will reduce the amount of data load and also make your execution faster. 
What is the number of records when you apply the filter **(f1.frq = 'B')** on cur_std_fundamentals. Having a partition on it depends on data distribution.

You can also break query by doing the self-join 1st and see the performance.

Do you have any compression used?

Comment: query worked after re ordering joins. Please check answer in the same section answered by me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked well after re ordering the joins.

> select 'B07C796' as
>   Sedol7,f2.ws_cd,f2.cntry_name,f2.entity_name,f2.stmt_sub_typ_desc,f2.stmt_typ,f2.item,f2.item_mnem,coalesce(f3.frq,f2.frq) as frq,coalesce(f3.frq_desc,f2.frq_desc) as
>   frq_desc,f2.yr,f2.seq,f2.fiscal_per_end_date,coalesce(f3.erng_rpt_date,f2.erng_rpt_date)
>   as
>   erng_rpt_date,f2.per_update_flg,f2.per_update_desc,f2.per_srce,f2.reported_curr,coalesce(f3.reported_val,f2.reported_val)
>   as reported_val,f2.exch_rate,f2.ws_curr,f2.unit_typ,f2.ws_val from
>   (select
>   f.ws_cd,f.ws_id,f.cntry_cd,f.cntry_name,f.entity_name,f.stmt_sub_typ,f.stmt_sub_typ_desc,f.stmt_typ,f.stmt_typ_desc,f.item,f.item_name,f.short_mnem,f.item_mnem,f.frq,f.frq_desc,f.yr,f.seq,f.fiscal_per_end_date,f.erng_rpt_date,f.per_update_flg,f.per_update_desc,f.per_srce,f.reported_curr,f.reported_val,f.exch_rate,f.ws_curr,f.unit_typ,f.ws_val
>   from (select comp_map.ws_cd from  (select qad_scrty_cd, typ  from
>   imdl_irdp_dev.cur_scrty_sedol_chg_hstry where given_qad_sedol in
>   (substr('B07C796',0,6)) ) chg_hstry join ( select ws_cd, typ,
>   qad_scrty_cd  from imdl_irdp_dev.cur_ws_comp_map) comp_map ON
>   chg_hstry.qad_scrty_cd = comp_map.qad_scrty_cd AND chg_hstry.typ =
>   comp_map.typ) f1 join (select
>   ws_cd,ws_id,cntry_cd,cntry_name,entity_name,stmt_sub_typ,stmt_sub_typ_desc,stmt_typ,stmt_typ_desc,item,item_name,short_mnem,item_mnem,frq,frq_desc,yr,seq,fiscal_per_end_date,erng_rpt_date,per_update_flg,per_update_desc,per_srce,reported_curr,reported_val,exch_rate,ws_curr,unit_typ,ws_val
>   from imdl_irdp_dev.cur_std_fundamentals_part where yr BETWEEN 2018 AND
>   2018 AND frq='A' AND stmt_typ in ('IS','BS','CF','Other')) f ON
>   f.ws_cd = f1.ws_cd) f2 left join (select frq, frq_desc, erng_rpt_date,
>   reported_val, ws_cd, item, yr, seq  from
>   imdl_irdp_dev.cur_std_fundamentals_part where yr BETWEEN 2018 AND 2018
>   AND frq='B' AND stmt_typ in ('IS','BS','CF','Other')) f3 ON f2.ws_cd =
>   f3.ws_cd AND f2.item = f3.item AND f2.yr = f3.yr AND f2.seq = f3.seq
>   ORDER BY f2.yr,f2.seq,f2.item;